# Session and Cookie not working with reverse proxy in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, reverse-proxy

I have created reverse proxy using IIS with below step.***(Environment setup)***

1. Hosted my website1 into IIS. (This website URL is website1.com)
2. Hosted my website2 into IIS. (This website URL is website2.com)
3. Create only 1 web.config file and hosted that as public domain in IIS as reverse proxy. (This website URL is localhost)
4. Now i open localhost and it loads the contain of website1.com.
5. And when i open localhost/web2 it loads the contain of website2.com

It is working fine as i expected and it is working by writing below code in localhost web.config file

```
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
              <rules>
                <clear/>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to web2" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^web2(.*)" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://website2.com{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Main" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://website1.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
              <outboundRules>
                <clear/>
                <rule name="Add application prefix" preCondition="IsHTML">
                  <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^(.*)" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(web2).*" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" value="/{C:1}{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                  <preCondition name="IsHTML">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                  </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
              </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

***PROBLEM/ISSUE***
Reverse proxy working fine but when it loads the contain of website1.com I found some error which is listed below.

1. Some place i am using session so by using reverse proxy when i hit localhost at that time i am not getting session value. The session value is null.
2. So i have converted session in to cookie. The same issue i found that cookie is storing in browser but i am getting null value while get that cookie with using reverse proxy setting.
3. While using website directly (when i hit website1.com), the website working perfectly.
4. Please note that site is developed in asp.net MVC.

I say my issue in one line that neither session nor cookie working with reverse proxy using IIS.

Can anyone help me ? I appreciate your efforts in advance.

Comment: Do you have a domain set in the [httpCookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms228262(v=vs.85).aspx)  <httpCookies domain="website1.com"

Comment: Thank for quick response. Yes I have set the domain but it is not working.

Comment: You should not set the domain,if you set the domain ,it will not work for reverse proxy scenario.

Comment: Could you take a fiddler trace and check what is the set-cookie header coming from the server ?

Comment: Kindly find header here : https://files.fm/u/xkpxpyx9#/
Also let me know if you need anything from my side. I didn't set domain as of now.